# Proving the centre of mass formula with integral

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, integration, geometry, calculus

I came across a question:

> Find $f(r)$ and prove the centre of mass formula:
>   $$\vec{r_{cm}} = \frac{1}{V} \int f(r)  \vec{dS} $$
>   Where $V$ is the total volume and our surface integral is over a body with uniform density.

I'm not even quite sure where to start. I spent a while fiddling around with the divergence theorem but to no avail. I think $f(r) =\frac{r^2}{2} $ but this is only a guess. Any hints would he great to get me started along the right track.

Comment: Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the density is uniform, the definition for the center of mass formula is:

$\vec{r}_{cm} = \frac{1}{V} \int \vec{r} dV = \frac{1}{V} \int 1 \vec{r} dV$.

Now you can use the rule for partial integration in three dimensions. By using

$\int \nabla(ab)dV = \int ab d \vec{S} = \int (b \nabla a + a \nabla b)dV$

and identifying $\nabla a = 1, b = \vec{r}, $ you get $a = b = \vec{r}$ and from above equation:

$\int \vec{r} dV = \int r^2 d \vec{S} - \int \vec{r} \nabla \vec{r}dV$.

The last term on the right hand side has the integrand $3 \vec{r}$ and you can put it on the left hand side. Then you will find $f(r)$.

Comment: I had never seen that integral identity before! Would you have any reference where I could read up on these/practice problems related to these identities ? Thanks

Comment: As I'm not quite sure why del dV = dS

Comment: You will find informations about such identity by seaching thinks like "vector analysis". Here, you can see the Gauss theorem for divergence: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem

Comment: video lectures are also more comprehensive than text https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/greens-theorem-and-stokes-theorem/divergence-theorem-proof/v/divergence-theorem-proof-part-1